# Buffered version of Go io.Pipe

Tags: go

Is there a buffered version of [io.Pipe](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe) (either in the standard library or a third-party library) before I roll my own?

Context: I'm trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229262/1536933) for parsing of JSON data compressed with bzip2, so that the decompression and parsing happen in parallel, but finding that the speed-up is very small. Parsing uncompressed data takes ~22 sec per million records. Decompressing that much data takes about the same time. Doing them on a single thread takes ~44 seconds, as expected. Using the solution above takes ~41 seconds.

The documentation for io.Pipe says:

> Reads and Writes on the pipe are matched one to one except when
>   multiple Reads are needed to consume a single Write. That is, each
>   Write to the PipeWriter blocks until it has satisfied one or more
>   Reads from the PipeReader that fully consume the written data. The
>   data is copied directly from the Write to the corresponding Read (or
>   Reads); there is no internal buffering.

I suspect this could be a problem, depending on the way the bzip2 decompressor writes data and the way the JSON parser reads it, so I'd like to try a buffered version.

Comment: What is your experience in your usecase? Was the buffered version better, faster, smoother? What was your final solution?

Comment: I don't remember, sorry. It was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the [`bufio`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio) package is for. It lets you turn any `io.Reader` into a buffered reader with [`NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReader), or any `io.Writer` into a buffered writer with [`NewWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewWriter).

(Whether buffered IO will actually help with your specific problem, I have no idea...)

Comment: This isn't quite the same. With using a `bufio.Writer`, the caller has to either call `Flush()` (which makes it blocking and thus defeats the point of buffering), or you deal with the reader getting data in bursts when the buffer fills up and flush is triggered automatically (which may end up blocking as well). For some this may be fine. But my own goal is to not block the writer in case the reader goes out to lunch, but to otherwise allow data through with minimal latency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a buffered pipe from https://github.com/djherbis/nio like this:

```
import (
    "github.com/djherbis/buffer"
    "github.com/djherbis/nio"
)

...

b := buffer.New(32*1024)
pr, pw := nio.Pipe(b)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want async operation, where reads are done on a separate goroutine you can also use a `readahead` I made a few years ago:

https://github.com/klauspost/readahead

Example:

```
ra := readahead.NewReader(input)
defer r.Close()
pr, pw := nio.Pipe(ra)
```

With default settings It will read up to four 1MB buffers that will be sent as the pipe is ready for it.

Comment: nio.Pipe of latest version has changed contract and can't accept ReaderWriter. There is "github.com/djherbis/buffer" with interface satisfying new contract.

Answer (score 0):

My https://github.com/acomagu/bufpipe has simple interface and works well.

```
r, w := bufpipe.New(nil)
io.WriteString(w, "abc") // No blocking.
io.WriteString(w, "def") // No blocking, too.
w.Close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
// Output: abcdef
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PdyBAS3pVob)